# Understanding output of np.corrcoef for two matrices of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I would like to compute the correlation between each *column vector* of matrix **A** with each *column vector* of matrix **B**.

Consider:

```
vectorsize = 777 
A = np.random.rand(vectorsize, 64)
B = np.random.rand(vectorsize, 36)
corr = np.corrcoef(A, B, rowvar=False)
```

The output of `np.corrcoef` in this case will be a 100x100 matrix. What does this mean?

Intuitively I'd expect to get a 64x36 matrix.

Comment: The duplicate question does show me how to do what I want, but it *does not bring me any closer to understanding the output of np.corrcoef*, which was my original question.

Comment: Yup, let's wait for NumPy gurus to write up the explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the  method corrcoef gets two arrays x and y, it stacks them (vertically if rowVar is True, horizontally if rowVar is False). 
In the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3019):

```
if y is not None:
    y = array(y, copy=False, ndmin=2, dtype=dtype)
    if not rowvar and y.shape[0] != 1:
        y = y.T
    X = np.vstack((X, y))
```

In statistical terms, it thinks A has 64 variables (in columns, since rowVar is false), and B has 36. Stacking them gives you 100 variables, hence the 100 by 100 correlation matrix.

Correlation matrix is always symmetric (and positive semidefinite). If you only want the correlations between x and y variables, they are in an off-diagonal block of size 64 by 36: extract it with slicing.  Here's the structure of the output:

```
 corr(x, x), size 64 by 64  |  corr(x, y), size 64 by 36
 ---------------------------+---------------------------
 corr(y, x), size 36 by 64  |  corr(y, y), size 36 by 36
```

Answer (score 4):

As `rowvar=False` it computes correlations between columns. Therefore it calculates the Pearson correlation coefficient between each column of `A` with itself and every other column of `B`. Its the same as you concatenate the two matrix and calculate the correlation between its columns, like bellow:

```
C = np.hstack([A, B])   # C.shape[0] == A.shape[0] == B.shape[0] and C.shape[1] = A.shape[1] + B.shape[1]

corr_C = np.corrcoef(C, rowvar=False)

np.allclose(corr_C, corr)   # Returns True
```