# Computing correlation between matrix - R and Python return different results

Tags: python, r

Let's assume matrix X and Y of size 2x3 and 2x2, respectively.
Function 'cor' in R returns a 3x2 matrix while function numpy.corrcoef in Python return a 5x5 matrix. Examples below:

R:

```
X<-matrix(c(0.2,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.5,0.3), nrow=2, ncol=3)
Y<-matrix(c(0.2,0.3,0.6,0.7), nrow=2)
cor(X,Y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]   -1   -1
```

Python:

```
X = np.array([[0.2,0.5], [0.1, 0.7], [0.5,0.3]], ndmin=2).T
Y = np.array([[0.2,0.3],[0.6,0.7]], ndmin=2).T
corr = np.corrcoef(X, Y, rowvar=False)

array([[ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

How to get python to return a 3x2 matrix like in R ? Or how should I select the correct values in Python's 5x5 matrix so it matches R's result ?

Comment: Perhaps it is doing as `cor(cbind(X, Y))`

Comment: I guess the reason is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846193/understanding-output-of-np-corrcoef-for-two-matrices-of-different-sizes).  Possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, when `x` and `y` are matrices, `cor(x,y)` will return correlation of columns of `x` (n=3) with columns of `y` (n=2). In python, you can slice the result of `np.corrcoef()` using the correct indices, which in this case are 3, and 2, for `x` (rows) and `y` (columns), respectively, of the result.

```
np.corrcoef(X,Y)[0:3,0:2]

array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.]])
```